# Themes, virtual path and base href

Tags: asp.net, url, path, themes

I have created a theme with a skin, including e.g. following:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" runat="server" SkinID="SquareCopy" 
    ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/MyTheme/square_copy.png" />
```

This would create (depending from what page I call it):

```
<img src="../App_Themes/MyTheme/square_copy.png">
```

What would I need to do if I only wanted (no `../`):

```
<img src="App_Themes/MyTheme/square_copy.png">
```

I tried to ommit `~/`: `ImageUrl="App_Themes/MyTheme/square_copy.png" />`

But this doesn't seem to have any effect. The reason why I want to have fix paths is the use of `base href` through the whole project.

Thx for any suggestions!

**Edit**:
Interesting, if I use a Image-Control without skin-id, I can make it render the path as I would like to have it:

```
<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server"
    ImageUrl="App_Themes/MyTheme/square_copy.png"/>
```

Results in:

```
<img id="MainContent_Image1" alt="Image text" 
    src="App_Themes/VolunteerClient/square_copy.png">
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by having this skin? are you saying that every image with that skin should display square_copy.png image?

Answer (score 1):

Base url of the element defined in skin file will always be

```
App_Themes/MyTheme/
```

where MyTheme is a name of your theme.
eg.

```
Path="~/App_Themes/MyTheme/Images/a.jpg"
```

will be resolved to 
    Path="App_Themes/MyTheme/Images/a.jpg"

also

```
Path="Images/a.jpg"
```

will be resolved to 
    Path="App_Themes/MyTheme/Images/a.jpg"

If you want to change that behaviour you will need to overwrite path.

Hope that helps

Comment: maybe for what you want to achieve you should use CSS ?

Comment: `Path="App_Themes/MyTheme/Images/a.jpg"` would be great, but if I call the skin in a page not residing within the root (e.g. one folder downwards), I will get `Path="../App_Themes/MyTheme/Images/a.jpg"`

Comment: CSS: Well, I have lot's of code-before with many elements like `<img alt="" src="pics/square_copy.png" />`. Now I need a second presentation (e.g. blue buttons instead of yellow), and I thought I should turn these places into image-controls and use themes instead?

Comment: yes indeed, that will always resolve the path to the theme folder. depending where the aspx file sits in the app, the path will be adjusted accordingly (so you might see multiple "../")

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
<asp:Image runat="server" runat="server" SkinID="SquareCopy" 
    ImageUrl="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/App_Themes/MyTheme/square_copy.png") %>" />
```

Comment: But then there would be no sense to use the theme-skin. I'd like to define the path in there for reocurring images/buttons etc.

Comment: If I am following what you want to do, then put "<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/App_Themes/MyTheme/square_copy.png") %>" in your skin.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I had forgotten no server directives in the skins.